# Counts rows that only have integer values mysql

Tags: mysql

I am new to mysql.
So I want to make a count vote with the votes column which only has an integer value, but when I use:

select count(votes) from table;

Which counts for 7 all rows in the votes column. I only want to display votes with a value, and not to display 0 votes.
My votes column use integer(int)

Here is my table:

select votes from table;

| votes |
| --- |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |

select count(votes) from table;

| count(votes) |
| --- |
| 7 |

So, I want it to be:

| count(votes) |
| --- |
| 4 |

So I just want to take an existing integer value with only 4 rows total, not 7.
Thank you

Comment: Use conditional sum `select count(*), sum(votes > 0) from table`, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `where` to filter it

```
SELECT count(*) FROM TABLE WHERE votes > 0;
```